# Xcode 13.3 Segmentation Error when Archived

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

After updating Xcode to 13.3 I am getting this error `error: Segmentation fault: 11` when trying to archive. I've tried changing the optimization for size `[-Osize]` but that didn't work. Is there any way to get around this other than reverting to Xcode 13.2.*?

I didn't have any issues until I updated

Answer (score 0):

Here is what solved my problem.
Go to `Build Settings` in your project target

1. Build Options - `Enable Testability` set `YES` for Release.
2. Swift Compiler - Code Generation set `[-Onone]` for `Optimization Level`